# pgfmathtruncatemacro going crazy

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

This is really weird. When I define distances with pgfmathtruncatemacro it usually works but there is one which does not work and makes no sense. If the name of the distance is overwritten by the real number it works. But this only happens to one distance, no matter the name you use. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}%to draw
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.IEC} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{petri}
\usepackage{circuitikz}%para dibujos con pouertas logicas etc
\usepackage{pgfplots}%graficas en tikz
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro \patitas {1mm}%distance for patitas de las puertas lógicas etc
\pgfmathtruncatemacro \ypatitas {1mm}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro \xpatitas {0mm}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro \auxd {1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro \noded {1 cm}%distancia entre nodos
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US,
                tiny circuit symbols,
                every circuit symbol/.style={fill=white,draw, logic gate                    input sep=1mm},
                node distance = \noded,
                decoration={
                markings,
                mark= at position 0.5 with {\node[font=\footnotesize] {\rotatebox{70}{/}};}
                }
]


\tikzset{font=\scriptsize}
%logic gate nodes

\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(1,0.5)$) (andpriman) {}; 
\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [above of =andpriman] (andprima1) {};
\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [node distance=\auxd cm,above of =andprima1] (andn) {};
\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [above of =andn] (and1) {}; 


% vdots

\path (and1.south) -- (andn.north) node [black, font=\large,midway,yshift= 1*\auxd mm] (vdots1) {$\vdots$}; 
\path (andprima1.south) -- (andpriman.north) node [black, font=\large,midway,yshift= 1*\auxd mm] (vdots2) {$\vdots$}; 

% carry on with nodes

\node[or gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [right of =vdots1] (orexcitatorias) {}; 
\node[nor gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [right of =vdots2] (norinhibitorias) {}; 
\node at ($ (orexcitatorias) !.5! (norinhibitorias) $) (aux1) {}; 
\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [right of =aux1]  (andgatherer) {};  

%connections        

\draw (andpriman.input 1) -- ++ (left:1mm) node[yshift= \ypatitas, left=\xpatitas,blue] (xpriman) {$x'_{M}$};
\draw (andpriman.input 2) -- ++ (left:\patitas) node[yshift=-\ypatitas, left=\xpatitas,blue] (wprimajn) {$i_{M}$};
\draw (andprima1.input 1) -- ++ (left:\patitas) node[yshift=\ypatitas, left=\xpatitas,blue] (xpriman) {$x'_1$};
\draw (andprima1.input 2) -- ++ (left:\patitas) node[yshift=-\ypatitas, left=\xpatitas,blue] (wprimajn) {$i_1$};
\draw (andn.input 1) -- ++ (left:\patitas) node[yshift=\ypatitas, left=\xpatitas,blue] (xpriman) {$x_N$};
\draw (andn.input 2) -- ++ (left:\patitas) node[yshift=-\ypatitas, left=\xpatitas,blue] (wprimajn) {$e_N$};             
\draw (and1.input 1) -- ++ (left:\patitas) node[yshift=\ypatitas, left=\xpatitas,blue] (xpriman) {$x_1$};
\draw (and1.input 2) -- ++ (left:\patitas) node[yshift=-\ypatitas, left=\xpatitas,blue] (wprimajn) {$e_1$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: The picture of the code above]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would mention which of your macros doesn't work.

Comment: \patitas was the macro that was the one which did not work. Anyway now I understand how to do it thanks to @Torbjørn T., whose answer has been exquisite.

Answer (score 4):

Calculations are done using `pt` as a 'unit' I think, so the 1mm is converted to points. Hence,

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\patitas}{1mm}
```

makes `\patitas` hold the value 2, since 1mm is approximately 2.8pt. Note similarly that `\pgfmathtruncatemacro \noded {1 cm}` actually makes `\noded` expand to 28.

If you want to make a macro that holds a length, you could use

```
\newcommand\patitas{1mm}
```

or if you need to do calculations, use

```
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\patitas{1mm}
```

You would also get something more like expected if you did `++ (left:\patitas pt)`, note the `pt`, but because of the `truncate`, the distance would be about 0.7mm instead of 1mm.